# How to merge two arrays into a map using Java streams?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, hashtable, java-stream

Lets suppose we were given the following two arrays

```
String[] keys   = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "aa", "d", "b"}
int[]    values = new int[]    { 1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4  ,  5 ,  6 }
```

And by merging these 2 arrays into HashTable we get the following

```
// pseudo-code
Map<String, Integer> dictionary = new HashTable<>(
  ("a"  => 1)
  ("b"  => 8) // because "b" appeared in index 1 and 5
  ("c"  => 3)
  ("aa" => 4)
  ("d"  => 5)
);
```

How can we do this using java Lambda style?

So far I have the following:

```
// this loops through the range given (used for index start and end)
// and sums the values of duplicated keys
tree.listMap = IntStream.range(range[0], range[1]).boxed().collect(
  Collectors.toMap(i - > dictionary[i], i - > i + 1, Integer::sum, TreeMap::new)
);
```

However, I'd like to take 2 arrays, merge them by key and value, where value is the sum of all values for duplicated keys. How can we do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There you go:

```
Map<String,Integer> themap = 
       IntStream.range (0, keys.length).boxed()
                .collect (Collectors.toMap(i->keys[i],
                                           i->values[i],
                                           Integer::sum,
                                           TreeMap::new));
```

Output:

```
{a=1, aa=4, b=8, c=3, d=5}
```

This is quite similar to the snippet you posted, though, for some reason, the snippet you posted contains no reference to the `keys` and `values` arrays.

Comment: There is a slight difference in the output of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46948467/1746118) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46948406/1746118). Just curious to know, does the `groupingBy` sorts the data as well?

Comment: @nullpointer `Map` makes no guarantees about iteration order so the output is for all intents and purposes the same.

Comment: @nullpointer My answer returns a `TreeMap` (as in the OPs code), so the keys are sorted. You can also modify the `groupingBy` solution to return a `TreeMap` (by default, the current implementation returns a `HashMap`).

Comment: Thanks Eran for your answer. I was kind of stuck on how we merge 2 separate arrays. Hence why you don't see any reference of keys and values. I have only obtained a single array prior to your solution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like using streams when referring to indexes, but you can use [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) and [`summingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to accomplish this:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, keys.length)
   .boxed()
   .collect(
       Collectors.groupingBy(
           i -> keys[i],
           Collectors.summingInt(i -> values[i])
       )
   );
```

Note that this works on the assumption that keys and values are both of equal length, so you may want to do some additional validation.

Comment: I didnt give too much focus towards sorted map. The requirement was simply to merge two arrays with given values as sum for duplicated keys. Have I been too vague in my question? Let me know and I'll edit. Regardless Michael, I appreciate your answer. It was very warming to learn something new :)

Comment: @Jamie Nope, your question was perfectly clear. Happy to help.